# centering icon in responsive div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center an awesome font icon (play) in it's parent div. I can achieve this by adding the proper padding with px but can't get it to stay center when the bootstrap grid is below a certain size (mobile).

1. Would I need to use javascript to achieve this or is it possible with css?
2. Is there a way to have the font-icon increase / decrease in size with it's parent div?

Animated gif showing the play button not maintaining the center.- http://www.gfycat.com/RespectfulBruisedFruitbat

Fiddle. I tried my best to recreate this.
http://jsfiddle.net/lazycoda/syxpq07b/3/

```
.fa-play:before {
    content: "\f04b";
}

.fa-play {
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 36%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using link shorteners, and linking to external sites. Replicate your issue with a Fiddle and post some code to show us your code.

Comment: Ok im on it! apologies for the mistake

Answer (score -4):

Check out the edited code let me know if it works for you.

```css
.primaryContainer {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#box {
  float: left;
  height: 657px;
  margin-left: 7.330357%;
  clear: none;
  width: 82.932351%;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
#box1 {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  width: 58.843155%;
  background-color: rgb(69, 0, 255);
}
#box2 {
  float: left;
  height: 100.014605%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  clear: none;
  background-color: rgb(237, 17, 17);
  min-width: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-play:before {
  content: "\f04b";
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
}
.fa-play {
  font-size: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">
  <div id="box" class="clearfix">
    <div id="box1" class="clearfix">
      <div id="box2" class="clearfix">
        <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syxpq07b/4/)

Comment: thanks for the input but on my fiddle example, the blue div is where the title name will be.  Also if you drag and shrink the browser you'll see the red div and blue div are responsive getting smaller. That's when the play button is no longer center.

Comment: does anyone else have any suggestions or to point me in the right direction?

Comment: ya its easy man. You can set the w/h to .fa-play on different break points as doing with red and blue box.

Comment: but the problem I'm having is shown on the gfycat link on the first post.  It's when the last breakpoint hits then the boxes shrink in size and the play button doesn't shrink with it.